# Refile Selected Text to Bottom of Header (Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to send the currently selected text/region to the end (or beginning; doesn't matter) of another header? This is similar to `org-refile`, which sends one header to another, but instead it's with just selected text.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig a little in `org-refile` you might notice that the refile target is selected using the function `org-refile-get-location`.  We can exploit that function to obtain a marker using the `org-refile` mechanism we like so much (and use that for relocating the selected region content):

```
(defun my/move-region-to-heading (&optional heading)
  "Move current region to a user-selected heading or programmatically to HEADING represented by a marker."
  (interactive (list
                (nth 3 (org-refile-get-location "Move region to: "))))
  (let* ((target-marker heading))
    (atomic-change-group
      (kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (set-buffer (marker-buffer target-marker))
      (goto-char target-marker)
      (org-back-to-heading t)
      (outline-next-heading)
      (insert "\n")
      (yank)
      (insert "\n"))))
```

Comment: When running, this yields the error "helm-M-x: Wrong type argument: markerp, 46534". I think the issue is with the line `(set buffer (marker-buffer target-maker))` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @George For some reason `heading` has a buffer position rather than a marker.  Did you invoke the command interactively?  What version of Emacs are you using?